# lsp-mode, Show Potential Fixes

Tags: lsp-mode

In lsp-mode, is the "Show Potential Fixes equivalent to the one in Visual Studio?

I have the following line in C#

```
        public static CloudStorageAccount CreateStorageAccountFromConnectionString(string
```

There is a red underline on CloudStorageAccount, so I try lsp-modeline-code-actions-mode, but the Echo area just says: "No code actions on the current line"

If I try this in Visual Studio, it gives me, under "Show Potential Fixes", the option to "Install package Windows.Azure.Storage"

Is this supposed to be supported or accessed any other way?

Comment: Do you have [`lsp-ui`](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-ui) installed?

Comment: Any suggestions for fixing code that you're getting from lsp-mode will come from the language server itself, so if you're using the same language server that visual studio uses (does it use one??) then they're at least *potentially* the same -- provided that both are using the same API call to the language server.

Answer (score 1):

You can try exploring the following commands.

- `lsp-modeline-code-actions-mode` - Toggle code actions on Emacs modeline.
- `lsp-execute-code-action` - Execute a code action selected from the list of available actions.
- `lsp-ui-sideline-apply-code-actions` - Choose and apply code action(s) on the current line.

You can see code actions recommended by `jdtls`.

[image]

Comment: Maybe I should've accepted this answer and asked another question, but they seemed so similar to begin with;). Sorry and thanks;) lsp-modeline-code-actions-mode does seem to work, but I was really after a way to have it suggest packages to install. I thought it was the same function.